# Laravel 8 view()->nest usage

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

our project coming from laravel 3.x, we'r upgrading to laravel 8 but we have a problem on nest, error says undefined function 'nest'.

```
return view('pages.' . Str::lower($this->table) . 'list', $data)
  ->nest('filterbar', 'sections.filterbar', $data)
  ->nest('commandbar', 'sections.commandbar', $data);
```

Comment: If I understand what `nest` did correctly, this would now be something that you include in your blade file rather than the controller https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#including-subviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you may wish to pass a view into another view. For example, given a sub-view stored at app/views/child/view.php . in old versions of laravel ,  we could pass it to another view like so:

```php
$view = View::make('greeting')->nest('child', 'child.view', $data);
```

The sub-view can then be rendered from the parent view:

```php
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello!</h1>
        <?php echo $child; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

and here where is the nest function is available .
but in newest versions of laravel , you can just include that child view in the parent view in order to use it .. using the blade directive @include can be really helpful at that point .

so instead of :

```php
return view('pages.' . Str::lower($this->table) . 'list', $data)
  ->nest('filterbar', 'sections.filterbar', $data)
  ->nest('commandbar', 'sections.commandbar', $data);
```

you can just return the parent view :

```php
return view('pages.' . Str::lower($this->table) . 'list', compact('data');
```

and somewhere inside these views , instead of using the subview , you would need to include it :

```php
@include('sections.commandbar')
```